# Does apply Single Tax Principle in that situation?

Tags: international, tax-law

Does apply Single Tax Principle in that situation:

Person is citizen of Chile, but currently lives and has residence in Ukraine and works remotely meanwhile Chile.

Does he need pay taxes in Ukraine?

Comment: It depends on the nature of any international tax treaties between the two countries.

Comment: Would you be able to update your answer to specify the countries involved?

Comment: There may not be tax treaties between the two countries. In any event, the answer will also depend up the national tax law of country Y.

Comment: thank you, I specified the question